# Parse Issue: Module 'stringByAppendingFormat' not found

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

Writing an iOs7 project, with Xcode 5

I have the following simple code

```
NSString* inflation=@"test'", *import=@"";
if ([inflation length]>0){
    import=[import stringByAppendingFormat:@"\nExports %@",inflation];
}
```

And I keep getting this error when I try to compile:
Module 'stringByAppendingFormat' not found

[image]

Comment: there is no problem in that block of code..problem is in somewhere else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LLVM uses `import` for importing modules (currently an experimental feature but seems to be enabled by default in Xcode). Have a look at [the docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html).

To resolve your issue, just rename the variable, or compile with "-fno-modules".

Comment: I want to add that Xcode is using different text colors for "inflation" and "import" which are both intended as variable names. It is important to pay attention to how Xcode applies syntax highlighting when investigating an error like this.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an issue with this code, so don't blame ios7 :P

Just change your variable name.

```
NSString* inflation=@"test'", *importString=@"";
if ([inflation length]>0){
    importString=[importString stringByAppendingFormat:@"\nExports %@",inflation];
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, this was very stupid of me. Of course, it worked in XCode 4.5, but not in 5. Thanks!